# Rayleigh damping in Finite Element Models using beta-coefficient only

Tags: ansys, finite-element-method

I am modelling a railway track in ANSYS where the different soil layers have different material properties (including different damping ratios).

Since I know what frequency of vibrations to expect in the track, I can model the damping ratio using beta-damping in the soil elements only. I do not want to use alpha-damping, since it is defined globally in ANSYS and therefore would apply to all other materials for which I do not want to include damping.

I have no problems in the results, but I need to justify why it is okay not to include the alpha-coefficient. I have found a [report online](http://designspace.com/staticassets/ANSYS/staticassets/resourcelibrary/confpaper/2002-Int-ANSYS-Conf-197.PDF) that says "In many practical structural problems, the $\alpha$ damping (or mass damping) which represents friction damping may be ignored ($\alpha=0$)."

However, I need either a published paper or relevant textbook, or a detailed justification why beta-damping is a good approach, and I have been unable to find it so far.

Comment: Your question seems to be looking after references, which is out-of-scope for this site.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have taken a better look at the rules before posting.

I will take that into consideration next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The report in your link explains it briefly in the sentence after your quote. The beta term models "structural" or "hysteretic" damping, which is described earlier in the report.

The key fact about hysteretic damping is that, for a fixed amplitude of motion, it dissipates the same amount of *energy* in each cycle of the motion, *independent of the frequency*. That is often a good model for "internal energy dissipation" within a structure. I'm not a civil engineer but I could imagine it is a plausible model for the ballast or earth under a rail track squidging about as it dissipates energy. It is certainly a good model for the (small) amount of energy dissipated by the metal rails themselves as they vibrate.

The alpha term doesn't have an obvious physical interpretation, but it can be mathematically useful. It has the same mathematical property as beta, namely that the mode shapes of the damped system are identical to the undamped. (In general that is not the case, and the damped modes can have different phases in different parts of the structure, i.e. they can look more like "travelling waves" than the undamped vibration modes). Using a combination of alpha and beta, you can get a fairly constant level of equivalent modal damping factors within a narrow band of frequencies, while the damping factors for modes with both higher and lower frequencies are more heavily damped. (That can be nice if you are modelling a system which is not fixed to anything, because the alpha term damps out any rigid body motion which you are probably not interested in, but the beta term does not).

Sorry, I don't have a reference for this (I've known it for too many decades already!) but a search for "hysteretic damping" should turn up something.

Bear in mind that modelling damping is rarely an "exact science". The best source of advice would be "best practice" in your particular application - either specialist textbooks, or relevant papers in journals. You are probably not the first person who wants to model this!

Comment: Thanks @alephzero. I have found a paper that kind of fits what I am doing. I already demonstrated why mathematically the beta-damping is equivalent to the hysteretic damping for a fixed frequency, it just goes somewhat against the common engineering wisdom of using both alpha- and beta-damping.